# Store the results in a separate NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

i was told to Use a Python program to compute ê for every row of the array and store the results in a separate NumPy array.

which example 1 or 2 (image) below being correctly displayed as a seprate Numpy Array?

[image: EXAMPLE 1]

---

[image: EXAMPLE 2]

Comment: Please do *not* post images of data/outputs or code. Post code, data, and outputs as *formatted text* in the question itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Compute exponent row wise

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array(([4.0,0.2,1.16,0.5],[6.0,0.1,0.06,-0.75]))
e = np.exp(np.sum(ar,axis=1)) # O/P array([350.72414402, 223.63158768])
# Take exponent and take some along axis 1
e = np.sum(np.exp(ar),axis=1)
```

Computing exponent element wise

```
e = np.exp(ar)
# To convert to single row
e =e.reshape(-1) # or single line e = np.exp(ar).reshape(-1)
print(e)
array([ 54.59815003,   1.22140276,   3.18993328,   1.64872127,
   403.42879349,   1.10517092,   1.06183655,   0.47236655])
```

Compute by multiplying with variable

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array(([4.0,0.2,1.16,0.5],[6.0,0.1,0.06,-0.75]))
s = np.sum(a,axis=1)
e_calculated = e ** s # (Where you can assing value of e)
# Calculating with np.power np.power(e,s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a 3*2 image. Probably "all rows" would mean doing operation e across the columns.  Just an example of `np.sum()`

```
>>> img=np.array([[1,1],[2,1],[4,1]])
>>> e=np.sum(img,axis=1)
>>> e
array([2, 3, 5])
>>> e.shape
(3,)
>>> img.shape
(3, 2)
>>> img
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [4, 1]])
>>>
```

However, it depends really on what your ê is which hasn't been posted.
It could be ê is being calculated for each element or 'element-wise' for which you would have to do as Rinshan stated in second part of his answer.
You should refer these diagrams to clear out which axis you need to perform e-hat on. This is only how much I can help you sorry.
[image]
[image]

EDIT: If e-hat is exp then you could sum across the columns then apply np.exp()